# iOS App Won't Compile After Migrating to Xamarin.iOS Unified API

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, monogame

I developed an iOS game a few years back using Xamarin Studio in conjunction with MonoGame and C#. I haven't checked on the app in a long while, but recently discovered it is no longer working (crashes on startup).

After doing some digging it looks like it is because Xamarin has moved on to the Xamarin.iOS Unified App. When I try to migrate the app though, I am running into a lot of problems.

Upon migration, my MonoGame.Framework reference is no longer valid. This means that all of my Microsoft.Xna references are also broken, which is the core of my game.

So my question is, what step am I missing? How do I get these references to work after upgrading to the Xamarin.iOS Unified API?

Comment: I would start by going over this guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/updating-ios-apps/ . You do need to make sure that your references are all able to work with the Unified API.

Comment: I did follow that guide.. I am able to convert it just fine, but after converting, then I am left with a ton of errors from the MonoGame stuff.

Comment: OK, this might provide some insight: http://community.monogame.net/t/ios-unified-64-bit-support/1347 , and this: https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/pull/3139

Comment: Found this too: https://blog.bitbull.com/2015/11/10/updating-legacy-xamarin-monogame-projects-to-ios9/

Comment: Could you post the diagnostic build output? It will help us troubleshoot the issue